# What is good practice with DB Services C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making web project in ASP.NET MVC. Every controller call service to do some operations. Lets take a look on example

```
 public interface IProjectService
    {
        bool ActivateProject(int projectId);
        //others
    }
```

And implemented class

```
 public class ProjectService : IProjectService
    {
        private readonly IContextProvider _contextProvider;

        public ProjectService(IContextProvider contextProvider)
        {
            _contextProvider = contextProvider;
        }

       public bool ActivateProject(int projectId)
        {
            using (var context = _contextProvider.GetContext())
            {
                var project = context.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectId == projectId).SingleOrDefault();
                project.Status = 1;
                context.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
        }
    //others
     }
```

In the example administrator wants to activate project. I have validation in jQuery so admin cannot pass nothing else than projectId.

So now what should return this method?
Should I leave it as void? 
Lets say there is an error with database so should I throw exception? Whats practice for this kind of operations ?

Comment: _"I have validation in jQuery"_ - that's not how you secure a web service.

Comment: What do You mean? I meant that parameter of method will always be ok

Comment: You can never trust user inputs. Just because you're passing the value from jQuery does not mean someone bypasses jquery and sends data directly to you. Validate server side, 100% of the time.

Comment: Of course I undestand so I should throw exceptions or what ? I dont know what is practice in those situations

Answer (score 2):

As general rule you should not use exceptions to handle standard execution flow. Exceptions are used  for situations where something that should not happen actually happened.

With that said, there is a border line where exceptions and return values fit well and it's just a question of taste.

Exceptions will normally provide more flexibility since you can throw different exceptions types and handle them with a single try / catch. They also provide much more information. A boolean doesn't say very much about what happened.

If you return a boolean, you should handling exceptions inside the method and at the very least, logging error details somewhere.

I'd personally throw the exception in case something went wrong and let the caller handle it.

Comment: You may have missed the "web service" part of the question. There's no way to throw an exception from a web service (it'll turn into a 500 response with a JSON payload describing the exception) and a client really can't "handle" those exceptions.